# Why do these cases not return IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions?

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I recently stumbled upon this. Why do the following cases not return IndexOutOfBoundsExceptions?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "String";
    System.out.print(str.substring(0, 0));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "String";
    System.out.print(str.substring(str.length()));
}
```

I've always been told that .substring(int i, int k) returns the substring from index i to k-1. In the first case, wouldn't the substring be from index 0 to -1? Why does that not produce an out of bounds error? I have the same question with the .length() case as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `String` [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) states an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown if:

> the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex.

Your examples do not meet any of those criteria, hence no exception is thrown. If the start and end index are equal, you will always get an empty `String` as a result.

I'm not quite sure what your question is for the second example. `.length()` simply returns the number of characters a `String` contains. In your example above, it would simply return the `int` 6.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java 8 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):

> ```
> public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
> ```
>
> Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at
>   index `endIndex - 1`. Thus the length of the substring is
>   `endIndex-beginIndex`.
>
> **Throws:**
>   `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the `beginIndex` is negative, or `endIndex` is larger than the length of this `String`
>   object, or `beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`.

Is `beginIndex` negative? No, it's 0.
Is `endIndex` larger than the length of the string? No, 0 < 6.
Is `beginIndex` larger than `endIndex`? No, they're both 0.

> I have the same question with the `.length()` case as well.

Why do you expect it to throw an exception? `length()` never throws.

Comment: A gotcha is you can get a `NullPointerException` if you try to call `.length()` on a `null` String, although you're right that it wouldn't be the `.length()` method throwing the exception, but rather the `null` String itself.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [substring javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-):

> Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

Therefore, `"String".substring(0, 0)` simply returns the empty string `""`

Looking at the [length javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--):

> Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of Unicode code units in the string.

Therefore `"String".length()` returns `5`.